# GET with Body in REST JAX-RS

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have one use case, implementing REST API through JAX-RS, which is just for retrieving some resources (**NOT creating/updating/deleting**).
And this API needs some big xml file content in request, which cannot injected in query paramaters.

So please suggest proper implementations for this case, as

- POST, is for create
- PUT, is for update
- GET, cannot send body through this.

Comment: If you have to implement the API, the method should be give and not decidable by you - if you have to implement the WebService by yourself, decide if it is public or used by you only - if used only by you you can even implement it as a RMI call and not sticking to REST principles.

Comment: This will be public API

Comment: we use POST, after all you are providing your server some big xml data. both POST and GET support retrieving data using a response so it's ok.